# Arabic text appearing reverse when Arabic text comes with digit

Tags: android, locale, arabic, textview

I need to print the below string which is in Arabic on `TextView` in Android. It is printing good but when the Arabic text and digits falls in a same string, Android put the digit at end!

here is my code

```
String str = "مقر 44";
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
textView.setText(str);
```

Here is the output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this workaround

```
 String str = "44 "+"مقر ";
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        textView.setText(str);
```

[image]

its not Android who put digit at the end, its because of Arabic writing standard